# XPages - error copying extension library controls

Tags: dojo, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus

I have copied some code from one custom control to a new custom control. The code
I copied contains some xe extension library and now all of these xe components show
error messages saying that prefix xe is not bound (The prefix "xe" for element "xe:djContentPane" is not bound). Is there any way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the line `xmlns:xe:...` to `<xp:view`

```
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
```

Comment: Additional tip: probably the fastest way to add the line is to drag an Extension Library control to custom control pane and delete it. Doing this the line `xmlns:xe:...` is added to `<xp:view` automatically and remains after deleting the temporary control.

Comment: @user1699830 - are you on Source tab? Then you can see what happens during drag- and dropping an Extension Library control.

Comment: @user1699830: good. Then, open Extension Library section on the right. Click on "Accordion" and drag it to XPage's or CC's bottom. That inserts `xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"` to `<xp:view`. Delete the also added `<xe:accordion id="accordion1"></xe:accordion>`.